# Sikuli run exception

Tags: sikuli

when i try to run sikuli from terminal with command

java -jar sikuli-setup.jar

i get follwoing exception

```
[debug] SikuliX Setup Build: 1.0.1 12NOV2013120000
[debug] ... starting with no args given
[debug] user home: /home/vivek
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:546)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:384)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1755)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1832)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1692)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:864)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:668)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:639)
    at org.sikuli.basics.RunSetup.popInfo(RunSetup.java:976)
    at org.sikuli.basics.RunSetup.main(RunSetup.java:424)
```

Comment: Did you read the installation instruction in Sikuli site?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you try to run it on a remote machine without graphical environment? You have to run the IDE on an active desktop (it requires the graphical environment).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong file. 
 
If you want to run sikuli you need the `runIDE.cmd` (version 1.0.1) or `runsikulix.cmd` (version 1.1.0) file.

The file you are calling is used for the setup.